# SolrNet - Score always 0

Tags: solr, solrnet

I have a simple query to a Solr instance using SolrNet, But for some reason, the score is always 0.

I have verified :

- have a field       [SolrField("Score")]
      public double Score { get; set; } in my mapping class
- have checked that the fields being searched are string instead of text.

What else could be wrong? Please help

Update:

```
  var results = solr.Query(q,
                                   new QueryOptions
                                    {
                                        OrderBy = new[] { new SolrNet.SortOrder("DateSubmitted", Order.ASC) },
                                        Fields = new[] { "score" }

                                    }
                                  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that score is in the list of fields when you do the request (the fl parameter) because the score is not returned by default.

Comment: Thanks is thsi construct (see above) sufficient? I tried this and still don't get a score.

Comment: I would first check directly with the Solr console if making a request with the fl param set to score returns documents correctly. Then I would check if the param is correctly sent to Solr with an http request analyzer (tcpmon or fiddler).

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. Figured it out.

Answer (score 8):

Just like Pascal noted, the score is not returned by default, so you have to do [fl=*,score to get everything and the score](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_see_the_relevancy_scores_for_search_results). In SolrNet this translates to `Fields = new[] {"*","score"}`.

Also mapping is case sensitive so you'll want `[SolrField("score")]` instead of `[SolrField("Score")]`

Comment: using **SolrNet** how can we get the `max()` so we can calculate a relevant percentage for each returned document?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to use the IndexField attribute instead of SolrField

```
[IndexField("score")]
public decimal Score {get; set;}
```